# Possible CartoDB SQL add-on?

Tags: carto, sql

Is there a possible add-on that will simplify the user experience when creating a SQL statement? More specifically, is there a GUI that would allow the user to create a SQL statement similar to ArcMaps's Query Builder where pre-built function keys and data specific variables appear in the query window? CartoDB is an excellent fit for my client, however the SQL function is a little daunting to them.

I'm very new to CartoDB, but  did a fair amount of research for potential solutions without any luck.  I did researched SQL API tool, but it is my understanding that the API only interacts with the data table by Inserting, Deleting, and Updating the data?

Comment: Did you take a look at the CartoDB filter tool? It applies SQL queries in the back but for beginners in this SQL world it's just selectors and buttons to play with.

Comment: Thanks iriberri!  I didn't realize that the filter tool creates a SQL statement.  This will serve my purpose, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I'm then moving the comment to an actual answer. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the right toolbar of the CartoDB Editor there's an option available for filtering data: it allows to select the column in which the information is, and then, depending on the type of the data, you can set which values you want to show and which not.

The filters are creating a SQL query in the back. If after applying a filter you go to the SQL tab you will see that the options that the user selected by means of user-friendly buttons are actually a SQL query that the user can also edit.

There's a tutorial about it [here](http://docs.cartodb.com/tutorials/filters/)